# chrome extension updating a textarea

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

There is a website with a textarea and the textarea has a class of `foo` and I trying to create a chrome extension to fill this textarea when I open the site, but for some reason my code is not working.

**JavaScript :**

```
window.onload = function(e) {
   if(window.location.hostname == 'www.foobar.com'){
      document.querySelector('.C_INPUT').value = "example text";
   }
}
```

This code does not work. If I grab another div and just modify the size of font it works, but not for this code.

I get in the console the following error.

> ```
> at Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
> at content.js:5
> ```

Yes, the textarea is empty, but I am trying to fill it, so not sur why this error keeps poping up

Answer (score 1):

**Try like as -**

```
window.onload = function(e) {
   if(window.location.hostname == 'www.foobar.com'){
      var C_INPUT = document.querySelector('.C_INPUT');
      console.log(C_INPUT); /*Debug here, You are getting null Object Here*/
   }
}
```

> **Note:** Debug your selector, It is getting null (No Element is selected)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the selector is incorrect, you mentioned textarea has a class `foo`but in code you are using `C_INPUT`

Edit:

```
window.onload = function(e) {
        if(window.location.hostname == 'www.foobar.com'){
            document.querySelector('.foo').value = "example text";
        }
 }
```